# Directory of C:\ File not Found

Tags: windows-10

So suddenly out of nowhere one fine dayy PC landed on the black screen with blinking underscore.
My OS was installed on a 240gb SSD
Is a system fresh install my only option? I'll try to copy any docs I need using command prompt. 
I do not have a system restore point.
Also, I'm fairly new to windows 10 and I'm not sure how to boot to safe mode.

I tried running Windows Setup from USB and accessing my C: drive but I receive the message above when I enter `C:` and then`DIR`. It appears my real C: is the H: drive in Windows Setup and C: is only 500MB.

Sorry I'm not that good with computers.

Comment: Drives you see in Windows PE (during windows setup) are not equivalent to drives you see while running Windows. Drives can be mounted anywhere and there is an additional X: drive. Your entire post is about this fundamental misunderstanding. So, if you need help diagnosing the actual issue, please better describe your problem because what you describe now is not actually a problem.

Comment: Hi, i understand what you are trying to say and where the X drive came from. But that is not my intent. My C drive got renamed to H, and now the C drive is only 500mb. That is my main problem and the fact that windows is not booting up. I appreciate the comment.

Comment: Based on your comments below. You aren’t understanding what we are saying. Your are not running “your operating system” as you know and love. You are running Windows setup in Windows PE. The drive letters are NOT the same and that has NO impact on your actual system. This is normal. The only part of your question that actually describes the real problem is the first sentence. Everything else describes a perfectly working environment. Please describe your actual problem and what you want to accomplish. Making H: be C: is not relevant at all.

Comment: Thank you. I understand now. I had no idea about this earlier, because i never checked the drives during system install or repair. I have edited the question.

Comment: No problem. I edited your question to provide relevant info so the answer below doesn’t sound completely off the wall.  It would help if you add details about anything that may have happened leading up to the issue. Did it appear after a restart one day, or after an update, after you walked away for a while, etc.? This problem doesn’t usually just occur instantly.

Comment: It actually did happen out of nowhere. I was using the computer in the afternoon, shut down and went out. I returned at night and started it up to find this problem. I haven't installed any new updates or softwares in the past week or so, other than antivirus updates.

Answer (score 1):

While you are in Recovery Mode, your drive mappings do not remain the same.

Rather than reinstalling Windows, try booting into Safe Mode, or if you are able to rollback to a system restore point, try that.

You may be able to transfer those necessary files through the command prompt just in case.

Here's how to do so:

- Switch to your "H:" drive by typing `H:`
- Navigate to the directory containing the files you need using `cd`
- Copy them to a separate removable disk using `copy * <drive letter>:` e.g. `copy H:\Users\myuser\Documents\* D:`
- Be sure to get any files you need before going through with a system restore in case it fails

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'll try the file copy method. But what I wanted to know was, is there any way I can get back the original C drive which got renamed to H? I tried rolling back to a system restore point but there seems to be none present.

Comment: Sorry to hear about the lack of a system restore point. That hurts to hear :(

When you get back to Windows it will show as C, but within Recovery Mode, the main Windows boot drive is remapped to another letter. The point here is not worrying about letters, its getting your data to a safe place and making as few sacrifices as possible in the process.

Comment: Now i understand. Sorry for the confusion. I'll edit the question.

Comment: This isn't a solution, but after you solve your problems, be sure to use this essential, but poorly advertised feature: https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-create-a-full-system-backup-in-windows-10/

Comment: Hi Steve. Thanks for that. I will definitely check and do it after i get my pc up and running.